# How to pass data from twig to controller using <a> (html link tag) in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, hyperlink, controller, twig

I would like to know how to pass data from twig to controller using  (html link tag) in Symfony2. Let's assume that we have a twig file called "test.html.twig" which has the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var a = "hello";
        var b = "hi";
        var c = $('<a href="">send data</a>');
        $('body').append(c);
    </script>    
</body>
```

How can I pass the values of the two variables `a` and `b` though the html link tag `<a>` to a controller in Symfony2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the variables as parameters to your controller as followed

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var a = "hello";
    var b = "hi";
    var c = $('<a href="/hello/' + a + '/'+ b +'">send data</a>');
    $('body').append(c);
  </script>    
</body>
```

[The Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html)

```
random_route:
  path: /hello/{a}/{b}
  defaults: { _controller: SomeBundle:Controller:Action }
```

[The controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html)

```
public function randomactionAction($a, $b) {
  // $a = 'hello', $b = 'hi'
}
```